# Are correlated sub queries supported by GraphQL

Tags: graphql, correlated-subquery

I am investigating the use of GraphQL

I have a use case which I cannot see how to achieve in a single GraphQL query.

I have the following data classes.

```
Type A Reference Data (Primary Key id)
Type A User Data      (Foreign Key rd_id)
Type B User Data
```

I can execute three separate queries to retrieve all the necessary data

What I would like is to execute a single query and get all data

I can get `Type A` & `B User data` in one query fine.

However I also need the `Type A Reference` data returned with the associated `Type A User` Data.

`Type A user` data has a foreign key to the specific reference data row

I cannot see how I can write a GraphQL query that joins data from two separate types of data.

```
query experiment {
  userA {
    id
    rd_id
    name
    address {
      address_line_1
      address_line_2
      zip
    }
  }
  userB {
    id
    business_name
    trading_as
  }
  referenceData (id : $userA.rd_id) { // How can I achieve this join
       type
       type_name
       limit
}
```

Does GraphQL allow me to join referenceData records to UserA type records like this in a "dynamic" way?

Comment: did u resolve this?

Comment: @thebluephantom, hi I am afraid I didnt solve this issue, maybe its possible now

Comment: Ok thx. It strikes me as quite difficult and that  resolvers only go so far